# Run Wear OS watch face as widget on phone

Tags: android-widget, wear-os, watch-face-api

## Abstract

I am a Wear OS watch face developer with few existing faces.
I would like to make them available as widgets on the phone.

Ideally, I would like to package the widget with the existing face to give more value to users.
They should be able to run the watch face on the watch and the widget on the phone independently.

## Background

Here is a quick glimpse of my `AndroidManifest.xml` entries

```
...
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
...
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone" android:value="true" />
...
```

Mutualizing the code should not be a concern as I suspect the `onDraw()` signature to be somewhat similar

## Question

Is this possible? If so, what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

There's very little commonality between the APIs for Wear watch faces and phone widgets. Widgets are built on `RemoteViews` (much more like Tiles on Wear OS), while watch faces are essentially live wallpapers for the watch.

I expect it would be possible to build a framework to display watch faces as phone widgets, but it would be a matter of building it yourself, from the ground up.